# Ограничение с помощью условных операторов

Tags: php

Например, есть следующее:

```
echo 1;
echo 2;
echo 3;
echo 4;
```

Какими средствами, можно вывести только 2 первых echo, т.е 1 и 2?

Comment: Не понятно. По точнее как то напиши. Ну если надо 1 и 2 вывести удали лишнее, или комментируй.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
if ($a+$a == $b) {
 echo 'fv allow';
} else {
if ($b-$a == $a-$a) {
 echo 'sv allow';
} else {
if ($a+$b*2 == 10) {
 echo 'tv allow';
}
}
}
?>
```

Например так, меняем значение переменных чтобы выполнялись разные условия.

Answer (score 1):

удалить
echo 3;
echo 4;
Это же очевидно!

Answer (score 0):

Если надо вывести 2 из 4-х, то два отсеиваются в любом случае по какому-то условию. А раз есть условие, то имеет место `if`